# Call method from within itself to execute again

Tags: ruby, recursion

What is the proper way in ruby to call a method from within itself to rerun
In the sample below when @dest_reenter is equal to yes I would want the b_stage method to execute again

```
def b_stage 
    if @dest_reenter == 'yes'
        @dest_reenter = nil
        b_stage
    end
end
```

Comment: That is correct the way it is written. Are you having any problems with the code?

Comment: btw, it's called recursion (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion)

Comment: I am using this concept in ruby however the execution is not happening again. I wonder if this is valid in ruby

Comment: Yes it is. You have a bug somewhere else in your code.

Comment: Then `@dest_reenter` must not be `'yes'`.  It is indeed valid Ruby.

Comment: What do you expect to happen? Nothing will happen if `@dest_reenter` isn't the string `'yes'`. There's no point to recurring at all here.

Comment: Did you try running it with the warning flag on? (`ruby -w`)

Answer (score 8):

That is how you do recursion, but using those instance variables isn't the way to go. A better example would be something like this:

```
def b_stage(i)
    if i < 5
        puts i
        i += 1
        b_stage(i)
    end
end
```

If you call `b_stage(0)`, the output will be

```
0
1
2
3
4
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a separate method:

```
def go
  ...
  middle_thing(true)
end

def middle_thing(first_time)
  next_page unless first_time == true
  parse_page
end

def parse_page
  ...(parsing code)
  middle_thing(false)
end
```